# Is there an overview of all my code projects on google code?

Tags: google-code

Is there an overview of all my code projects on google code? What is the URL I can visit?

My projects are not included in the dashboard at https://www.google.com/dashboard/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They should be listed on:

`http://code.google.com/u/youremailaddress`

This may also work:

`http://code.google.com/u/yourusername`

They should also be listed under "Projects" in the "My favorites" menu in the top right.

Comment: this is very nice, i was searching for half an hour already - OP karlthorwald - aka