# PUBLICLY link to all my projects on Google Code

Tags: google-code

Obviously any signed-in user can view his hosted projects on Google Code by browsing to http://code.google.com/u/yourusername (identified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132036/is-there-an-overview-of-all-my-code-projects-on-google-code)). I'd like to share this view with anyone by means of linking to the overview from my website, but of course it generates an error for anyone other than myself.

Anyone have any ideas of how I can either publicly link to this page OR somehow easily link to an overview of all my projects from my site?

Answer (score 1):

The "Profile" link in the upper right hand corner goes to your canonical public URL. Whether that's /u/username or /u/ depends on how you've set your email address to be displayed - for example, mine is http://code.google.com/u/artdent/.

Comment: right...but I can't view your profile and you can't view mine...so that's not public